botocore.eventstream.InvalidHeadersLength
I am trying to invoke Bedrock agent using boto3, and I am getting the following error:
botocore.eventstream.InvalidHeadersLength: Header length of 1953527156 exceeded the maximum of 131072

Here is the code I am using:
import boto3
import uuid

bedrock = boto3.client('bedrock-agent-runtime', 
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region_name=REGION
)

response = bedrock.invoke_agent(
    agentId=AGENT_ID,
    sessionId=str(uuid.uuid4()),
    inputText=INPUT_TEXT,
    agentAliasId="",
    enableTrace=False,
    endSession=False
)

stream = response.get("completion")
if stream:
    for event in stream:
        chunk = event.get('chunk')
        print(f"Agent Chunks: {chunk}")

What could be the issue?

I don't have an agent to test now. Can you try these instead? 1/ Point your agent alias to the working draft: `agentAliasId='TSTALIASID' 2/ Get the completion following this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/bedrock-agent-runtime_example_bedrock-agent-runtime_InvokeAgent_section.html

Hi, @Isc. Yes, that was the problem. Adding Alias ID fixed issue. Thanks a lot

Add TSTALIASID as the agentAliasId to invoke your working draft. Details in the user guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/agents-test.html
response = bedrock.invoke_agent(
    agentId=AGENT_ID,
    sessionId=session_id,  # you may want to save this ID for multi-turn conversation
    inputText=INPUT_TEXT,
    agentAliasId="TSTALIASID",
    enableTrace=False,
    endSession=False
)

